# Ошибки про загрузке node_modules

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Всем привет.
Хочу развенуть у себя проект, но сталкиваюсь с целой волной ошибок.
Как решитть проблему пока ума не приложу.
Может кто сталкивался с подобным ?
Предполагаю что где-то имеется несовместимость версий

Ошибки при npm i
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

надеюсь достаточно хорошо видно.
Ноду обновлял.
Пайтон также зачем-то просило утсановить. Ставил и последнюю версию и 2.7

часть package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
"@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.5",
"@quasar/extras": "^1.13.1",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"core-js": "^3.6.5",
"jssip": "^3.9.1",
"quasar": "^2.4.0",
"single-spa-vue": "^2.5.1",
"vue": "^3.0.0",
"vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
"vue-good-table": "^2.21.11",
"vue-good-table-next": "^0.2.1",
"vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
"vuex": "^4.0.0-0",
"vuex-persistedstate": "^4.1.0"
```

С самим по себе проектом все в порядке.
Я сейчас откопал старый ноутбук и без проблем развернул там его:(

Comment: Сталкивался как то с такой ошибкой, все верно это несовместимость версий а именно если память не изменяет то дело в версии ноды но это не точно.

Comment: @spl33t тоже сошлись на мнении что проблема с совместимостью версий.
вопрос чего именно.
У меня надо была 16.15 - ошибки
Обновил до последней - ошибки
У коллеги 16.16 - у нее все ок.
На старом ПК какая-то 14 нода, там тоже ок

Comment: @VadimTregubenko `node-sass` случаем в devDependencies не ставите?